# How do I use my Google Developer API Key with node-googleanalytics?

Tags: node.js, google-analytics-api

I'm currently in the process of trying to increase my rate limit from 1 qps to 10 qps so I can create a metrics-based app.

I registered the application at https://code.google.com/apis/console, received an API key, and changed my rate limit to 10 qps.

However, I'm using the node-googleanalytics library (https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-googleanalytics) in my project and it's unclear how to apply my API key to the project.

Has anybody had experience using this library, or a comparable one within the node ecosystem, do get data from the analytics APIs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the `token` parameter in the config?

See [here](https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-googleanalytics#usage) (second code block)